# Cannot see RPI ad-hoc network from android phone

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I installed on RPI zero W a ad hoc wifi network, through this github project:
https://github.com/simondlevy/RPiAdHocWiFi

I works perfectly with my mac, and my iphone, so I can connect correctly (please note that I see the wifi network as a "device" in the network list).

The pb I have is that I cannot see and connect from an Android phone. With a sniffing app I can see the network, but in the network settings the essid doesnt even show up.

Any idea on what to test/analyze?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read the issues, do you have an idea on what to change?

Comment: What I want is just a routerless wifi to which I can connect to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see what the script you used is doing. It is two years old and at a glance it modified `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and uses `/etc/rc.local`. The former should be used with caution as noted by the author, the latter is deprecated, and should not be used at all. You should better ask the author and read the issues.

But you wrote in a comment:

> What I want is just a routerless wifi to which I can connect to

For this it not needed to use an ad-hoc network. You can just use a standalone WiFi access point. You can find many up to date tutorials on the web showing how to do it. One solution is shown at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). There have a look at section **♦ Setting up a stand alone access point**.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I don't need the connection to internet, just between the pi and a mobile phone, does it apply also in this case(my pi won t be connected to ethernet)?

Comment: Yes. Please understand the simple drawing to the section **♦ Setting up a stand alone access point**. It shows exactly what you want.